# best way to realize backbone list application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-boilerplate

I use backbone.boilerplate for creating a simple application.

I want to create module that can show collections of sites. Each sites has id and title attributes (example `[{ id: 1, title: "github.com" }, { id: 2, title: "facebook.com" }]`.

My router:

```
routes: {
  "": "index",
  "sites": "sites"
},

sites: function () {
  require(['modules/sites'], function (Sites) {
    var layout = new Sites.Views.Layout();
    app.layout.setView('#content', layout);
  });
}
```

So, my sites module has layout, which do this:

```
Sites.Views.Layout = Backbone.Layout.extend({
  template: "sites/layout",
  className: 'container-fluid',

  initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);

    this.collection = new Sites.Collections.Sites();
    this.collection.fetch({
      success: this.render
    });
  },

  beforeRender: function () {
    var siteList = new Sites.Views.SiteList({
      collection: this.collection
    });

    this.setView('.content', siteList);
  },
});

Sites.Views.SiteList = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: 'sites/list',

  beforeRender: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (model) {
      var view = new Sites.Views.SiteItem({
        model: model
      });
      this.insertView('tbody', view);
    }, this);
  }
});

Sites.Views.SiteItem = Backbone.View.extend({
  template: 'sites/item',
  tagName: 'tr',

  serialize: function () {
    return {
      title: this.model.get('title')
    };
  }
});
```

ok. and now my question: help me please to choose best way to render one site view when user click on element of collection. I want that it is works like gmail: one screen for all letters and all screen for one letter when it choosed. Maybe you have link with example of similar application. I am waiting for your advices.

Comment: This is an incredibly broad question that almost amounts to "please architect my  site for me" (or maybe "please explain to me how to build a major Backbone-powered site").  Either way, questions of that broad of a nature aren't ideally suited for Stack Overflow; I think you'll have better luck either: A) reading some Backbone tutorials or articles, or B) asking a more specific question here.

Comment: ok, I understand you. I don't want that you do my job and create site instead me =) I just want to understand how that must works.
this is my variant, maybe you can see it and tell me what do you think about this idea? thx you
http://pastebin.com/VvPcPnQX

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pastebin code it seems like you have a basic understanding of Backbone, which is certainly all you need to get started.

That being said, you might find this article/tutorial helpful.  It walks through the process of building inter-connected views (in the tutorial they are related `<select>` elements) which use AJAX to update their values:

http://blog.shinetech.com/2011/07/25/cascading-select-boxes-with-backbone-js/

Comment: it's very usefull article. I'll try to transle it into russian and publish it in habrahabr.ru

but at first I try to rewrite my module =)